# How to have the useEffect and useLocation hooks sync up correctly in React using React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router

I am making an app where mousewheel up and down are used to navigate to and from different pre set routes.

currently the routes look like this:

**main -> skills -> aboutme -> work**

mousewheel-down cycles from left to right in the order above, and mousewheel-up does the same but in reverse.

this is the logic:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Context = React.createContext();

function ContextProvider({ children }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => handleNavigation(e));

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("wheel", (e) => handleNavigation(e));
    };
  }, [location]);

  function handleNavigation(e) {
    if (location.pathname.includes("/work/")) {
      return;
    } else {
      if (e.deltaY > 1 && location.pathname === "/") {
        navigate("/skills");
      } else if (e.deltaY < 1 && location.pathname === "/skills") {
        navigate("");
      } else if (e.deltaY > 1 && location.pathname === "/skills") {
        navigate("/aboutme");
      } else if (e.deltaY < 1 && location.pathname === "/aboutme") {
        navigate("/skills");
      } else if (e.deltaY > 1 && location.pathname === "/aboutme") {
        navigate("/work");
      } else if (e.deltaY < 1 && location.pathname === "/work") {
        navigate("/aboutme");
      }
    }
  }

  return <Context.Provider value={{}}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
}

export { ContextProvider, Context };
```

now this is working perfectly fine however in the `work` component I have nested routes (e.g. `/work/blahblahblah`) where I don't want the mouse wheel to scroll to different routes, so you can see on the first line of the `handleNavigation()` function I added a simple conditional where if the `location.pathname` contains `/work/` to return out of the function and not run the logic below.

However I have found that this is not working, when I scroll to the `/work` route and then click to go into the nested route scrolling still runs the logic below the if statement taking me to routes which I did not intend for, if I for example manually in the address bar go into the nested route such as `/work/foo` and then try scrolling my if conditional works correctly and scrolling on that page does not navigate me to different routes.

for a replicable example please look here:

[image: Edit fast-sky-kbm006]

scroll with the mouse wheel down to the `/work` route and then click the link to take you to the `/work/click-here` link.

I have tried playing around with the `useEffect` dependency array but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving the function `handleNavigation` inside the `useEffect` and pass the named function to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`, it fix the issue for me.

This is because `useEffect` need a reference so it can clean up the previous `listener` when dependencies change, and start a new one.

Also, there is no need to manually pass `event` to a `listener` since it is automatically given the `event` object when triggered.

Lastly I took out `pathname` for use in `useEffect` so it has a lighter dependency.

Example:

```
const { pathname } = location;

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleNavigation(e) {
      if (pathname.includes("/work/")) {
        return;
      } else {
        if (e.deltaY > 1 && pathname === "/") {
          navigate("/skills");
        } else if (e.deltaY < 1 && pathname === "/skills") {
          navigate("/");
        } else if (e.deltaY > 1 && pathname === "/skills") {
          navigate("/aboutme");
        } else if (e.deltaY < 1 && pathname === "/aboutme") {
          navigate("/skills");
        } else if (e.deltaY > 1 && pathname === "/aboutme") {
          navigate("/work");
        } else if (e.deltaY < 1 && pathname === "/work") {
          navigate("/aboutme");
        }
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener("wheel", handleNavigation);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("wheel", handleNavigation);
  }, [pathname]);
```

Hopefully the above code would fix this issue for now.

However, you might also want to consider moving this event handling to a regular wrapper component, instead of in `useContext`.

This is because `useContext` is intended for sharing data between components, yet these events clearly are for handling views and does not really use it's feature.

There are many approaches, but here is a quick example:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const { pathname } = location;

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleNavigation(e) {
      if (pathname.includes("/work/")) {
        return;
      } else {
        if (e.deltaY > 1 && pathname === "/") {
          navigate("/skills");
        } else if (e.deltaY < 1 && pathname === "/skills") {
          navigate("/");
        } else if (e.deltaY > 1 && pathname === "/skills") {
          navigate("/aboutme");
        } else if (e.deltaY < 1 && pathname === "/aboutme") {
          navigate("/skills");
        } else if (e.deltaY > 1 && pathname === "/aboutme") {
          navigate("/work");
        } else if (e.deltaY < 1 && pathname === "/work") {
          navigate("/aboutme");
        }
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener("wheel", handleNavigation);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("wheel", handleNavigation);
  }, [pathname]);

  return <>{children}</>;
};

export default Layout;
```

The above component can be used to wrap around your `Routes` and should provide same result (make sure to remove `ContextProvider` if testing).

Comment: you are an absolute genius! great easy-to-follow write up! thanks for your advice. that fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Well, first - you should not be doing this in a context provider. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) you can learn about context in react

Your bug appeared because you pass different links to handleNavigation in add and remove event listener functions. The link changes between renders, because you create new handleNavigation function each time and the variable holds a link to new place in memory. The listener doesn't get removed, old location value remains in the closure, so the bug happens

Regarding your question - the best way to do this is to make custom hook useScrollNavigation that uses useLocation, adds event listener on mount and removes on unmount. I would use this hook in a [layout component](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#layout-routes) that wraps all the routes that need this behavior, so it just unmounts when user navigates to different route. You also could pass an array of routes where you need this behavior, like that you won't need a layout route.